# How to add Children to Grid asynchrony?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, asynchronous, wpf-controls, addition

I have a Canvas with ca. 100 Lines and Ellipses.
Now I add 100s of these Canvas to a WrapPanel. This process takes ca. 4-5 Seconds.
Is there a Way to add/load these Canvases asynchrony? I didn't found a way to do so and Dispatcher.Invoke doesn't work (because it is not asynchrony).

Thanks for any suggestion...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure async is the solution here, as I read your question it sounds like you're adding many thousands of UI elements to the UI which are all triggering.

Still not much to go on but...

There is only one UI thread so any work that can offloaded elsewhere will improve performance.

- try adding Debug.WriteLine to your logic and use a StopWatch object to time stamp them. You can trace where delays are being created.
- review the code which sets up the lines and ellipses, how are you calculating any properties such as size and position. If this can be loaded into an array using an async Task method, you might get some responsiveness back.
- are all the elements visible on the screen at the same time. If not, only load the ones that are by using a virtualizing panel.

If you need more pointers, you might have to share the code.

Comment: Thank you for reply! I have a UserControl with one canvas with 10 Ellipses and 20 lines. Now I'm adding 100s of these UserControls with MyWrapPanel.Add(New MyUserControl)

Comment: I tried all these methods. I prefer the 2nd method BUT I can't create an new Ellipse/Line object out of a non-STA (?) Thread...

Comment: Do you have the code available to share? I think that's the only way anyone can come up with a different suggestion.